# Sublime Text 3 Emmet customization

Tags: css, sublimetext3, emmet

I am using ST3 with Emmet (Windows 7 64-bit) and I want to add some custom snippets, for example, the CSS for an iPad-specific media query.

I can't find any Emmet settings file, so how can I do this? I have tried creating a standard Sublime Text 3 snippet, but it doesn't work, so I assume these are disabled by Emmet to avoid conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Emmet documentation](http://docs.emmet.io/) has a [Customization](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/) section, which describes how to use a [`snippets.json`](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/) file to create your own snippets.

From the Customization link:

> Almost all officially developed editor plugins (...) has **extensions support**: a special folder where you can put .json and .js files to extend Emmet. Please refer to README file bundled with your editor’s plugin to find out where Emmet looks for extensions.

From [the README file](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet) (also found [on GitHub](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#readme)):

> In `Emmet.sublime-settings`, define `extensions_path` setting and Emmet will load all `.js` and `.json` files in specified folder at startup.
>
> The default value of extensions_path is `~/emmet`, which points to *emmet* folder inside your OS user’s home folder.
>
> Also, you can create sections named as extension files (e.g. `snippets`, `preferences` and `syntaxProfiles`) inside user’s `Emmet.sublime-settings` file and write your customizations there. See the [original settings file](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/blob/master/Emmet.sublime-settings#L61) for examples.

Comment: Well I read that but it is far from clear. Quote: "Create snippets.json file in extensions folder". What does it mean by 'extensions folder'? I copied the existing snippets.json folder into the packages/user folder but that didn't work. Am I expected to create a folder called 'extensions' and should it be in the 'installed packages' folder with the Emmet folder or maybe in the Packages folder or what? Why can't documentation be more specific?

Comment: @Perkin5 see my edit. The documentation is quite specific.

Comment: Thanks for that but it still leaves me stumped. The emmet.sublime-settings file is inside an archive in the installed packages. I've discoverd that I can open the archive with 7-Zip but I can't open/edit the file to change the extensions_path. Even if I could, is there not some problem in Windows that the separators have to be backslashes whereas ST3 requires forward slashes? Sorry if this sounds dim but if I was cleverer I wouldn't have needed to ask in the first place.

Comment: @Perkin5 no problem. Package settings are accessible via the **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> PackageName -> Settings-Default`** and **`... -> Settings-User`** menu items. `Default` is read-only, so all changes need to be made in `User`. Sometimes `User` is already populated, other times it's empty, so if it is what I do is copy the entire contents of `Default` to `User`, then alter things there. Anything in `User` will override the same setting in `Default`.

Comment: YES!!!! I copied the snippets.json file to a new Emmet subfolder in the Packages folder, used the Package Settings-User as you described to change the default extension_path, put a test snippet in the json file and up it came like a charm. I feel as if I should now document this for other idiots like me - but, worrying thought, maybe there aren't any! Many many many thanks!

Comment: Done that and again TY